# Get data from multiple dropdown select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a button that add a new dropdown select on the UI. How can I take all the data for different dropdown select

first dropdown have options=> water,apple,orange and I select water

second dropdown have options=>apple, orange and I select orange and so forth

This is what I done so far I don t have any idea how do this

```
const food = [
  { value: "water", label: "water" },
  { value: "apple", label: "apple" },
  { value: "orange", label: "orange" },
];

function App() {
  const [serviceList, setServiceList] = useState([{ service: "" }]);

  const handeleServiceAdd = () => {
    setServiceList([...serviceList, { service: "" }]);
  };

  const handleServiceRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...serviceList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setServiceList(list);
  };

{serviceList.map((singleService, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="services">
        <div className="first-division">
            <Select options={food}></Select>
                {serviceList.length - 1 === index && (
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className="add-btn"
                    onClick={handeleServiceAdd}
                >
                    <span>Add a Service</span>
                </button>
              )}
        </div>
        <div className="second-division">
            {serviceList.length > 1 && (
            <button
                type="button"
                className="remove-btn"
                onClick={() => handleServiceRemove(index)}
            >
                <span>Remove</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Instead of passing `food` as the options variable, try passing `food.filter(d => !serviceList.includes(d))`